# google auth and firebase persistence

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

heres my log in function, it works it logs you in via google account, but on refresh it does not stay logged in. what am I doing wrong? sorry I have no idea how to format the code to show correctly here.

```
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();


const  login = () => 
{setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence)
    .then(()=> {
        signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    .then((result) => {

        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
        const token = credential?.accessToken;
        // The signed-in user info.
        const user = result.user;
        //console.log({ credentials, token,  user });
       
        
    })
    .then(() => {
      setSignIn(true);
      
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // Handle Errors here.
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // The email of the user's account used.
        const email = error.email;
        // The AuthCredential type that was used.
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
        //console.log({ errorCode, errorMessage, email, credential });
    });
```

})

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase automatically restores the user credentials when you restart the app, but your code only responds to the explicit sign in (`signInWithPopup`).

To pick up the automatic restore (and other changes in authentication state), you should use an auth state listener as shown in the first code sample in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    var uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks, ive just started learning firebase at the start of the week so im still in the weeds here. if i understand correctly i need to move my sign in with popup into the onAuthStateChanged?  or a completely separate function? the google tutorial had a simple code like function initFirebaseAuth() {
  onAuthStateChanged(getAuth(), authStateObserver);
} and it worked in the tutorial but not my app.

Comment: makes sense ill give it a shot, I appreciate you taking you're time to answer my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Since v9, the code has changed.

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    const uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```